# How can i add this popup.xml to this fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments

Hello i want to add a popup window to a fragment i tried a lot of things still nothing i have. If someone helps me it will be great.

Here is my Fragment code;

```
public class Info extends Fragment {

public Info() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.info, container, false);
}
```

Here is my fragment.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonShowCustomDialog"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Show Custom Dialog" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is my popup.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/pozitif"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="dfdfdsfs"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image"/>/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/dialogButtonOK"
        android:layout_width="100px"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=" Ok "
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/image"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a DialogFragment. 
Instead of extending your Activity with Fragment, use DialogFragment
In on createView of the DailogFragment Activity inflate your layout

```
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dialog, container, false);
```

Find your View elements

```
TextView Message = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.text_view1);
```

To call your DailogFragment use this

```
 MyDialogFragment dialog = MyDialogFragment.newInstance();
 dialog.show(getActivity().getFragmentManager(), "MyDialogFragment");
```

For more info on this you can check out this link.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html